# Difficulty in understanding summation changing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I would like to understand how the sum of primitive roots of unity $$\sum\limits_{n , (k,n)=1}^{n} e^{2i\pi\frac{n}{k}}$$ give us the mobius function $\mu$. It involves changing of summation which I am unable to understand. I would like to know how to handle summation changing in general as it is coming in analytic number theory many times.

Comment: Look for "Ramanujan sums" on Wikipedia.

Comment: In pages 15-17 of, it seems that are a free course notes https://www.mtholyoke.edu/~robinson/reu/reu05/rdineva1.pdf you have a detailed proof, then if you want, after study it, tell to the community as an answer of yourself question where was your doudt. I know another, I read it in a book of Ram Murthy, but this last uses Ramanujan sums, trivially but you need too this definition

Comment: The problem is in the steps such as  $$\sum_{\gcd(k,n)=1}e^{2\pi ik/n}=\sum_1^n\sum_{d\mid\gcd(k,n)}\mu(d)e^{2\pi ik/n}=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_0^{(n/d)-1}e^{2\pi idk/n}$$ where we are taking sum of primitive n roots of unity. How did they removed that gcd condition in second equality.